# Excel shows 1:30 passed between 12:30 and 13:00

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get a calculation of h:mm between two different times. I am using this formula

```
=TEXT(D21+E21, "h:mm")
```

When the Two cells are `12:00` and `12:30` or `12:00` and `1:00` it shows `:30` and `1:00` respectively. When it is between `12:30` and `1:00`, it shows `1:30`. Note, all times are times of day.

Ultimately I want four cells, Time In, Time Out, Lunch In, and Lunch out, with a timespan showing time minus lunch. I am having trouble getting excel to give my anything close to accurate for nearly any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
=TEXT(E21-D21, "h:mm")
```

(changed E2 to E21 to match the original question JMG)

Comment: Of course those two things are different, I mean, why would addiction/subtraction need to be mutable. This works, but that fact is a bit annoying.

Comment: I see, it works as long as your 1:00 is specified as PM, or if you use 13:00.

Comment: @Tyrsius I don't understand what is annoying, E21+D21 is significantly different than E21-D21.

Comment: @JeremyGoodell I really don't know what I was just thinking. My brain was just failing.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you **don't** use TEXT function. As the name implies - the result of TEXT function is a text value, which you might not be able to use in subsequent calculations. It should be sufficient to use just

`=E21-D21`

...then format result cell as [h]:mm

Answer (score 0):

Change it to TEXT(E21-D21, "h:mm") and also use 13:00 instead of 1:00, or add dates.  It will fail if E21 is less than D21, and 1:00 is translated as 1AM.  If you want to get the difference across days then add date information as well.